# openvpn3: session-start: how to pass username and password

Tags: openvpn

Currently I am using openvpn3 client to connect to vpn server as

```
openvpn3 session-start --config /home/user/client.ovpn
```

then it asks for username and password.

Is there any easy way to pass username and password. Because everytime to enter username and password is annoying

Answer (score 9):

You can pass username and password with `printf` using `\n` as a delimiter:

```bash
printf "MY_USERNAME\nMY_PASSWORD\n" | openvpn3 session-start --config client.ovpn
```

Comment: This helped me in a more broad way. I was not aware of the printf function.

Answer (score 1):

openvpn3 session-start as per
https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux

> See the instructions on
> https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux how to
> install pre-built OpenVPN 3 Linux packages on Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora,
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS and Scientific Linux.

When I did an upgrade to Fedora 36 the latest openvpn3-linux v18 client was built in. Did not have to manually upgrade / install it:

```
openvpn3-admin version --services
```

e.g: previous v17 suddenly stopped working spend 10 hours trying to debug with many "openvpn3 session-start":

```
openvpn3 config-import --config profile.udp.ovpn --persistent
openvpn3 config-manage --config profile.udp.ovpn --enable-legacy-algorithms true --show
openvpn3 session-start --config profile.udp.ovpn
openvpn3 sessions-list 
openvpn3 session-manage --config profile.udp.ovpn --disconnect
```

Actually thinking it was a `cipher AES-256-CBC` legacy issue that others were having. It was not for some reason, permissions on install of the OpenVPN3 Linux client? as it was NOT creating a **TUN**.
So [I made one myself](https://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces) (that was the actual issue):

```
sudo ip tuntap add name tun0 mode tun
sudo ip link show
```

and it connected after **asking for VPN Username & Password**, so added those to text file `login.txt` in the profile directory and
`auth-user-pass login.txt` to `profile.udp.ovpn` so it would pass username and password automatically.

Another solution to pass the username and password is to use [openvpn3-autoload](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/blob/bcb93b4bdf67278951bd1eb2ce724e792ceba5ca/docs/man/openvpn3-autoload.8.rst)

FYI more openvpn3-client session start help is here: https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues?q=cipher

Comment: OpenVPN3 does not support `auth-user-pass`: https://openvpn.net/blog/openvpn-3-linux-and-auth-user-pass/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple python script to connect to VPN:

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn

commands = "openvpn3 session-start --config profile-40.ovpn"
commands_list = commands.split(" ")
username = "x"
password = "x"

session = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(commands)
session.expect("Auth User name: ")
session.sendline(username)
print("first_done")

session.expect("Auth Password: ")
session.sendline(password)
print("second_done")
```