# How to I pass a values to a program from shell script

Tags: shell, openvpn

I am trying to run openvpn client from shell script. When Openvpn client is lauched, it asks for username and password:

```
fkhan@fahads-hp:~$ openvpn3 session-start --config $OPENVPN
Using configuration profile from file: /home/fkhan/Downloads/.client.ovpn
Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/0e383f0es926es4553s8b29se340119cceae
Auth User name:
Auth Password:
```

To connect, one has to enter "Auth User name" and "Auth Password".  How do I pass those values through a shell file so I don't have to enter those values manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218533/10971581

Answer (score 0):

You can do some script automation tasks using `expect` command. In Ubuntu linux, you can simply install it - `sudo apt install expect`

Ref: [Use Expect in a Bash script to provide a password to an SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-a-bash-script-to-provide-a-password-to-an-ssh-command)

Comment: There's no need for `expect` in this use-case.  Installing it may generate new possiblities for hackers. Use caution.